# Best way to structure AWS's DyanomoDB for user accounts?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

This is from an Android context. I'm using Amazon Web Service's sdk to build an Android app that has basic social media functions. I'll need to store users, their posts, misc data, etc... I'm thinking of structuring it like this:

One big Table called "Users" which will contain an Item for each user. And then just have a ton of attributes for each user that stores all of their posts and misc data.

But I'd love to hear other opinions on how I should best structure this thing. I have essentially no experience with this sort of thing so I can't help but suspect that I'm going about this wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways you might go about your design. You should consider the usage patterns of your system to derive a design that is reliable and scalable.

I wouldn't mix posts with user information in the same table. Instead I would have a table of users, presumably identified by some sort of identifier - it might be the user's e-mail address, a unique account id, or some other surrogate unique key. It's ok to store meta-data about the users in this table. Then I would create another table of posts. The posts might be partitioned by user id and sorted by time-stamp. You might also consider having another more coarse time attribute, such as the date and create a GSI to index posts by date and time in order to be able to retrieve recent posts. The granularity of this could also be hourly if you'll have a lot of posts.

You should start to think about:

- how many users do you expect to have - will you have hundreds, thousands, millions
- how many daily active users do you expect to have?
- how many posts will a typical user make?
- will posts be spread through the day, or will they be clustered together
- what are the most important aspects to you? fast message delivery/retrieval? reliable message delivery/retrieval? online/offline message delivery?
- do you need support for group posts (ie. multiple users collaborating on the same thread)?

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the informative comment! I have a lot to think about now. I asked this question on another forum and most people were recommending the use of Amazon's Relational Database Service instead of their DynamoDB database. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I think you'll have to start answering those questions I included in my answer; relational databases are better at some things (ie. complex joins; transactions across multiple tables) while non relational (NoSQL) databases, DynamoDB included, are better at other things (ie. scaling horizontally; high availability) - so you have to choose based on your use case and goals